# Wiring for 2 plugs to replace a 2-in-1

Tags: wiring, cord-and-plug

Good day, all.

Could you please help me with a wiring question?

A 2-in-1 plug panel on wall but it’s damaged. I only have 2 separate plugs so planning to replace it.

There are 3 wires I found behind. What I am thinking is, if I can separate each of them (by using separator & extra small string of wires) and connect them individually into the separate plugs.

It shall be look like the picture.

Would it work?

And once connected, if the switches will work? What I am worrying is, either switch will not function, i.e. switch 1 but turn 2 off something like that.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Home Improvement Stack Exchange. This is a good question. Typically in US Installations this can be done. Please check the instructions that came with your new outlets. They should have a diagram confirming this. Jumpers can also be used from one outlet to another, if the switches are wired directly to the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I have done was directly connect the 3, to A (needless to say colours matched with colours). then use another 3 additional short strings of wires (from the connectors A which accepts the inputs) to connect A and B.

it's been weeks and both working fine.

[image: something like this]